# Updating multiple Redux store items in one go

Tags: javascript, redux

In my Redux store I have an array of threads, and an array of replies. Each Reply has a thread ID to associate it with a thread. When getting a thread from the database, the reply count is one of the properties returned, and the count is display in the web page alongside the thread.

My challenge surfaces when a user adds a new reply. The API returns enough information for me to add the new reply to the reply collection. But I also want to increase the reply count property of the thread, which is inside the thread array. How would I do that?

These are my (simplified) Reducers:

```js
const thread = (state = {}, action) => {
    let nextState = state

    if (action.type === C.POST_MESSAGE) {
        nextState = action.payload
    }
    return nextState
}

const threads = (state = initialState.threads, action) => {
    let nextState = state

    if (action.type === C.POST_MESSAGE) {
        nextState = [thread(null, action), ...state]
    }
    return nextState
}

const reply = (state = {}, action) => {
    let nextState = state

    if (action.type === C.POST_REPLY) {
        nextState = action.payload
    }
    return nextState
}

const replies = (state = initialState.replies, action) => {
    let nextState = state

    if (action.type === C.POST_REPLY) {
        nextState = [...state, action.payload]
    }
    return nextState
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you are dispatching an action when a reply is created somewhere (the 'POST_REPLY' action I suppose).

Remember that a dispatched action is available in EVERY reducer of your application, so if you want to update the threads state, you just have to respond to the `POST_REPLY` action in the threads reducer accordingly.

```
const threads = (state = initialState.threads, action) => {
  ... // other logic to update the threads list
  if(action.type === 'POST_REPLY') {
    // increment the reply count here and return the new thread list
    // action.payload would be the reply object in this case
  }
  ... // other logic to update the threads list
}
```

Now you can update a specific thread using the information in the reply.
Remember that you have to return a new object every time there is an update.

```
const threads = (state = initialState.threads, action) => {
  ... // other logic to update the threads list
  if(action.type === 'POST_REPLY') {
    const reply = action.payload;
    const index = state.findIndex(i => i.id === reply.threadId) // index of the thread in the array 
    const newThread = {...state[index], replies: state[index].replies + 1}
    return [
       ...state.slice(0, index), // copy threads before this index
       newThread, // the updated thread
       ...state.slice(index) // copy threads after this index
    ]

  }
  ... // other logic to update the threads list
}
```